# Copy conditional formula to separate columns GoogleSheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I've got a simple conditional formula to make cell green if there is more than X not empty fields. It works fine but I need a way to copy that formula to other columns. When I do it the simply click and drag way, it copies the formula but is still based on values from column D.

I want it to be like:
Colour green if there is more not empty values in column X than specified in cell X21.
Colour green if there is more not empty values in column Y than specified in cell Y21. etc.
[image: Single column]
[image: Formula]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the relative and absolute reference would help you with this.
There are 3 types of them:

1. $A1     Allows the row reference to change, but not the column reference.
2. A$1     Allows the column reference to change, but not the row reference.
3. $A$1    Allows neither the column nor the row reference to change.

In your case, I think you only want the column to change, which is the second one.

for more info, you can read this: http://web.pdx.edu/~stipakb/CellRefs.htm